# Checking how long vehicles have been parked

Tags: python, dictionary, micropython

I'm writing a program in micropython that is supposed to be able to tell if a vehicle is parked in the parking space and how long the vehicle has been parked. I managed to write the code for one sensor, however I want the code to be able to check more than one sensor at a time. I currently have two sensors that I'm testing with and I don't know how to get the program to count the times separately. I've tried playing with dictionaries but can't seem to get it to work.
Basically I want each sensor connected to their own time.time(). So let's say a car is parked on sensor_1, I want it to start counting for that sensor until the sensors value is back to 1 (no car parked) I'm not sure what's the right way to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
import time
from machine import Pin

def board_1():
    sensor_1 = Pin("P14", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_2 = Pin("P15", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_3 = Pin("P16", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_4 = Pin("P17", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_5 = Pin("P18", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_6 = Pin("P19", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_7 = Pin("P20", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_8 = Pin("P21", mode=Pin.IN)

    sensors = [sensor_1, sensor_2]

    time_parked = {"sensor_1" : 0, "sensor_2" : 0}

    while True:
        for i in sensors:
            if i.value() == 0:
                time_parked.update({str(i) : time.time()})
                if time.time() % 2 == 0:
                    print(keys, "parked")
                    time.sleep(5)



board_1()
```

Comment: Please explain the relationship between your "code so far" and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is `str(i)` returning?. Also the `time_parked.update()` will replace the time value, ist that what you want? Or do you want to accumulate the time?  So something like; `time_parked["sensor_2"] += 10`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Basically I want each sensor connected to their own time.time(). So let's say a car is parked on sensor_1, I want it to start counting for that sensor until the sensors value is back to 1 (no car parked) I'm not sure what's the right way to do that. Also str(i) seems to be returning the value of i, and not "sensor_1" as I was hoping

Comment: Add your explanation to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first draft, awaits more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

```
import time
from machine import Pin

def board_1():
    sensor_1 = Pin("P14", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_2 = Pin("P15", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_3 = Pin("P16", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_4 = Pin("P17", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_5 = Pin("P18", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_6 = Pin("P19", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_7 = Pin("P20", mode=Pin.IN)
    sensor_8 = Pin("P21", mode=Pin.IN)

    # Set up mapping(dict) of sensor identification strings to sensor classes.
    sensors = {"sensor_1": sensor_1, "sensor_2": sensor_2}

    time_parked = {"sensor_1" : 0, "sensor_2" : 0}

    while True:
        # Iterate over sensor mapping. Use the sensor id string to 
        # fetch value from class. Then use the id string to update the
        # time_parked dict.
        for sensor in sensors:
            if sensors[sensor].value() == 0:
                time_parked.update({sensor : time.time()})
                # Not sure what the below is supposed to do?
                if time.time() % 2 == 0:
                    print(list(time_parked.keys()), "parked")
                    time.sleep(5)
            # Update to reset timer.
            elif sensors[sensor].value() == 1:
                time_parked.update({sensor : 0})




board_1()
```

Questions that need answering:

1. How do handle when sensor.value() == 1?
2. As of now you are recording a point in time. For parking purposes don't you want to know the actual interval a vehicle is parked for?

Comment: When sensor.value() == 1 I want it to set the time_parked value back to 0. The goal is to be able to send the information. I want it to check how long a car has been parked, if it has been parked for a certain time, it should start sending information over, and do it in an interval. The "if time.time() % 2 == 0:" part is just a test currently before I write the code to be able to send data. The reason I want to check how long a car has been parked is so that it is able to see if a car has parked for longer than it's allowed.

Comment: Added to above to reset timer when `sensor.value() == 1`.  Where are you going to deal with calculating the interval a car has been parked?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to do.
Anyway, there is a colon missing after

```
    for i in sensors**:**
```

and keys in line 24 is not defined yet. Did you mean i.keys()?

Comment: I must've accidentally deleted that colon when editing the code. But what I'm trying to do is get the value of each sensor in time_parked to get updated when the sensor reads 0, which means that a car is parked there. print(keys, "parked) is supposed to happen every 2 seconds after the car has been parked. I'll try to put i.keys() instead